# How can I find row index?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to find row index in wpf datagrid according cell value. How can I do it ?

For example

```
gataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGrid.CellValue('abcde')
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking in the cells of one column or all?

Comment: Provide more context. A row has multiple cells, which cell are you evaluating to determine whether you've found your row or not?

Comment: I need to select row. I found cell value with LINQ from SQL Table. But datagridview index and SQL table index is different.

Comment: You're not being clear about what you want. I'd encourage you to at least write some pseudo code in your question.

Comment: show us how you are setting your itemssource

Comment: 'var satir = ta.GetData().Select(s => new { s.Plaka, s.Firma_Adi, s.Malzeme_Adi, s.Tartim_2,s.Index})
                                            .Where(p => p.Plaka.Contains(txt_PlakaNo.Text))
                                            .Last();

                    if (satir.Tartim_2 == 0)
                    {
                        
                        dgYuklemeler.SelectedIndex = satir.Index
}

Answer (score 0):

I found solition like that

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dataGrid.Items)
                {
                    if (row.Row.ItemArray.Contains('value'))
                    {
                        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(row);
                        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(row);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }  
                }
```